# Proof of Version of Krasner's Lemma

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory

I need some help in constructing the proof to this version of Krasner's Lemma from Serre's Local fields text book:

Let E/K be a finite Galois extension of a complete field K. Prolong the valuation of K to E. Let x be in E and let {x_1, x_2,...,x_n} be the set of conjugates of x over K, with x=x_1. Let y in E be such that ||y-x|| less than ||y-x_i|| for all i greater or equal to 2. Show that x belongs to the field K(y).

(Note that if x_i is conjugate to x over K(y) then ||y-x||=||y-x_i|| )

Comment: By Galois theory if $x\notin K(y)$ then there is an automorphism of $E$ fixing $K(y)$ which moves $x$. That's the only thing you need to finish the proof.